# Header using with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am developing an application. For the security reasons I used json ajax calls with GET method. 
First I would like to ask first thing is that is there any way to hide my data which send in AJAX JSON request, I want to protect it from Hacking.

Secondly I am using headers with my PHP function files. Header are :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 100");
```

Any one tell me these headers are okey and safe for AJAX CALLS?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding your data?

Comment: when ajax call send to php file using GET method it will show some data in response. I want to hide that.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to prevent yourself from a [man in the middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) hack or any sniffing of your network traffic, 
if so you need to configure your [website to be accessed via HTTPS](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/).